# what is best practices to implment .net core web api authentication by sms service

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

What is the best practices  to implement authentication on .net web api for mobile application  by mobile  number only no email no password

i search on internet how to implement it but all resources was how to implement two factor authentication 
Thank you